# ipython notebook is not updating when I change my code

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

So, I ran into a weird issue using an ipython notebook and not sure what to do.  Normally, when I run a part of the code, if there is an error, I would trace it back, fix it, and then re-run the code. I was doing a similar thing but even after making changes to the code, it looks like nothing is changing!

Here is the example... I am using Python 3.5 so xrange is gone.  This then caused an error to be thrown:

```
XXXX
     24     XXXX
     25     XXXX
---> 26     for t in xrange(0,len(data),1):
     27 
     28         XXXX

     NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined
```

but after changing my code (which you can see below the difference in line 26), the same error pops up!

```
XXXX
     24     XXXX
     25     XXXX
---> 26     for t in range(0,len(data),1):
     27 
     28     XXX

     NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined
```

Any ideas on why this would be happening?

Comment: can you share a [mcve]? From your error description it's very hard to guess what's going on.

Comment: I'm guessing you're changing an external file that you've imported. Imported files aren't automatically reloaded. You can explicitly reload it with `importlib.reload(mymodule)`. This especially catches out people used to Matlab, so IPython has an [autoreload extension](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html) that tries to automatically reload imported modules when they change.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you @ThomasK this ended up working! :)  Just an issue of updating the import files.  Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem!

Answer (score 24):

Whenever using external files along with Ipython use autoreload. It will reload the external files every time before executing any code in IPython.

Add this at first cell of the IPython.

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

Answer (score 13):

As [Thomas K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434217/thomas-k) said, you're probably making a change in an external file that was not imported. There is a very useful command in IPython notebook for such cases, called **autoreload**. With autoreload, whenever you modify an external file you do not have to import it again because the extension takes care of it for you. For more information check: [ipython autoreload](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html).

Answer (score 12):

For me this was due to **one of the following**:

> - Cause 1: imported module not updated

**Solution:**

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(your_module)
```

> - Cause 2: other

**Solution:** restart the kernel, for jupyter notebook this is how
[image]

Comment: The `%autoreload` method wasn't working for me, but using `importlib` did. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. I tried jupyter magic `autoreload` but it didn't work. Finally, I solved it in this way:
in the first cell, add

```
import My_Functions as my
import importlib
importlib.reload(my)
```

But notice if the module is imported in this way:

```
from My_Functions import *
```

I couldn't reload it properly.

Comment: That worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue sometimes.  I think it has to do with memory - if I have a bunch of dataframes hanging around it seems to cause issues.  If I restart the kernel using the Kernel > Restart option the problem goes away.

Comment: If it is a memory problem, you could also do %reset, or garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem sometimes. I restarted the kernels but it didn't work.I try to run the cell (ctr+ enter) two or three times. then the result will be displayed according to the updated codes. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

insert new empty cell with + option, go to Kernel, choose Restart & Run All.
Then, fill in the new inserted cell and run again in Kernel, choose Restart & Run All.

It works with me.